# Get filename in dropzone using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

hy guys I try like this, my quetion is how I can grab filename or name..?

```
 console.log(myDropzone.files);
```

[image]

Comment: `console.log(myDropzone.files[0].name);`

Answer (score 3):

`myDropzone.files` returns an array of File objects. You could access specific file properties using index.

Eg.

```
 console.log(myDropzone.files[1].name);//Getting second file name
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to dropzone.js and find

Dropzone.prototype._finished() function and alert this

responseText.success

you will get the file name